# Teradata 15.10 - Remove set of characters from a string

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a list of phonenumbers in the following format:

```
+7(000)1234567
```

I need to remove ),( and + symbols to recieve this:

```
70001234567
```

What function should i use?

thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `regexp_replace` to replace all non-numerics with blanks.

```
regexp_replace(phone,'[^0-9]','')
```

Answer (score 3):

If you know there's only '()+' you can simply apply `oTRANSLATE(phone, '()+', '')` to remove those characters, might be more efficient than a regular expression.